# ORA-12705: Cannot access NLS data files or invalid environment specified Oracle V 12.2.0.7 Windows 10

Tags: windows, oracle, nls-lang

I am trying to login into sqlplus at the windows command prompt and get the ORA-12705 error.
I have tried setting the NLS_LANG variable to a couple of times (as shown below) with no success.

set NLS_LANG=american_america.US8PC437

set NLS_LANG=ENGLISH_UNITED KINGDOM.WE8MSWIN1252

I have searched the install log files to see if I can find the NLS settings at installation time and couldn't find any details.

The NLS settings in the init.ora are shown below.

nls_language="ENGLISH"
nls_territory="UNITED KINGDOM"

Any help on how / what value to set the nls variables to would be really appreciated.

Thanks

Glyn.

Answer (score 0):

my guess would be to open Windows registry HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Oracle<your_client> and to check what NLS_LANG parameter set to. Then set it in the command window.

Anotther try would be to unset this parameter by just renaming it in the registry to. Like "old_NLS_LANG" or something similar.

Please don't do that on production server without trying on a test environment

Comment: Hi there, thanks for your suggestion. I renamed the NLS_LANG parameter to OLD_NLS_LANG and rebooted. sqlplus / as sysdba worked fine, a step forwards, however a startup open command returned "ORA-12700: invalid NLS parameter value (nls_language)". I checked the alert log and no errors were reported. Any further help would be really appreciated. Thanks Glyn.

Comment: @GlynWIlliams what was in the NLS_LANG in the registry? Or what is it now in OLD_NLS_LANG ?

Comment: It looks like the whole database is corrupt. So I'm going to reinstall and go again. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @GlynWIlliams yeah, that would be my next guess - when someone uses codepage and language like yours and runs into problems with NLS - it is a bad sign for the database. BTW, if you get in database settings trouble next time I think it would be better for you to try to get some help on dba.stackexchange.com - if I got it right, it is the place where all the database administrators live. Good luck